# Excel VBA - Validation Data and comma delimited strings

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I am trying to create data validation cells purely with VBA. The problem is, if one of the 
items in the validated list is a Excel formula which contains commas (such as the IF() in the following code) an error is generated.

```
 Dim str As String
 str = "=IF(SUM(A1:A2) = 0, ""Zero"", SUM(A1:A2)) , Item 2 , Item 3 , Item 4"

 s1.Range("B6").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
          AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=str
```

The error (runtime error 1004) is generated because it delimits the string at the first comma, so the first item of the validation is `"=IF(SUM(A1:A2) = 0"`. I'm hoping there are escape characters for the commas (such as \ in C) to avoid this.
I want the validated list to appear as such:

```
<result of IF() function>
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

Note: I CANNOT use a range for the validated data. If the user deleted the range the spreadsheet would be broken.

Comment: Do give as much information as you can while posting a question. What is the error generated? Does the error explicitly indicate that it has a problem with escape characters or is that your inference? Do edit the answer to include the error.

Comment: At least in Excel 2003, I don't believe you can mix formulas and lists in validations. See if you can do what you wish to accomplish in Excel (maybe with the macro recorder on). You could expand your formula to test against the other items, but then you won't get a drop down box if that was important.

Comment: you could use a range and place it on an xlveryhidden and locked sheet, unless your user is savvy with vba, they won't even know its there.

Comment: That's why it's not an answer, the formula1 option of data validation won't accept a list as far as i know. What you could do is create the list into an array and then create the validation based off of the array.

Comment: It does accept lists, but it delimits them based on commas, so it doesn't work with Excel Formulas that require commas (although it will work with something like =SUM(A1:A2) b/c there are no commas.)
I was not aware that you could pass an array to the formula1 option. I've tried, and it hasn't worked, could you show me an example? That would be a perfect solution!!

Comment: Assuming you can create the array with the result of your formula yourself, all you need to do is take the array and convert it into a string.

say your array contains "yes" and "no":

    `Dim arr As Variant
    Dim arrayString As String
    arr = Array("Yes", "No")
    arrayString = Join(arr, ",")`

then:

    `s1.Range("B6").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=arraystring`                                                               Doug has a cleaner solution though

Comment: +1 to @scott's suggestion about `xlveryhidden and locked sheet` - this is my everyday trick for the same cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a WorkSheet_Change event to reset the data validation when cells A1 or A2 change?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ValidationString As String
Dim rngChanging As Excel.Range
Dim rngWithValidation As Excel.Range

Set rngChanging = Range("A1:A2")
Set rngWithValidation = Range("B6")
If Not Intersect(Target, rngChanging) Is Nothing Then
    With rngWithValidation
        .Validation.Delete
        If WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngChanging) = 0 Then
            ValidationString = "0"
        Else
            ValidationString = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngChanging)
        End If
        ValidationString = ValidationString & ",Item2,Item3,Item4"
        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=ValidationString
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is clever. But doing this for every data validation field (365) on the sheet would be impractical. 
I find it hard to believe the only way to use formulas with data validation is do put the formulas in a range... but I guess this is just VBA

Comment: So, is the item list different for each validation? If so, you'll have a lot of code anyways. If not, then you might be able to define two named ranges, one with the summed cells, one with the lists. Assuming there's some pattern to them, catch any change in the sum range and apply data validation to the corresponding cell. I've done something similar to this in the past and it wasn't too bad.