# Excel validation list from range + a single value

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a list of names arranged in a *table* under the column `BM Name`. 
I want to add this to a **validation list**, which is working for me, however I also want to *append/insert* **another value** (preferably shown as the **first value** in the validation list).

I tried variations of the code below.
For reasons I do *not* want to simply *append* the value to the original table as it is dynamically created from an external source.

```
Sub Val()
Dim tbl as ListObject
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
    With ws.Range("ChosenBM").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!" & tbl.ListColumns("BM Name").DataBodyRange.Address
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="Default BM" ' Code fails here
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With ' Validation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add a different item on top of a Validation list**

Referring to [MS Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.validation.add) when using 
a `xlValidateList` type:

> Formula1 must contain either a **comma-delimited list** of values or
>     a worksheet reference to this list.

So instead of referring to a **range** you'll have to pass a **comma-delimited list**.

The shortest/fastest way *(avoiding loops in the data range)* would be to

1. assign the needed values to an array and
2. join them using a comma.

Step **`[1]`** is done easily via `v = Application.Transpose(tbl.ListColumns("BM Name").Range)` 
(BTW it's necessary to redimension from a 2-dim array to a "flat" one by transposing).

As you want to include another value in the first place, it's best not only to refer to the `DataBodyRange`,
but to include the **complete** listobject range thus including its title row (row 1).

Eventually you'll have to change the
column title (`"BM Name"`) to your special item's title (`"Default BM"`) via

```
v(1) = "Default BM"
```

Step **`[2]`** is executed by the right `Formula1` argument `Formula1:=Join(v, ",")`

Further note: *Of course it would have been possible to simply prefix the resulting list by the new item string separated by a comma :-)*

**Example call**

```
Sub ValidateTableColumn()
Dim ws  As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
With ws.Range("ChosenBM").Validation
      ' [1] Assign the needed values to a variant array (including the column title)
        Dim v
        v = Application.Transpose(tbl.ListColumns("BM Name").Range)
        v(1) = "Default BM"                 ' << Change first item to new one
        .Delete
      ' [2] pass a comma-delimited list by applying Join() function to the array
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
             AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
             Formula1:=Join(v, ",")          ' << pass the comma-separated list
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With ' Validation
End Sub
```

Comment: One issue I see with this is that if me values contain a comma it, i.e. a value `Testing , with comma` becomes to instances `Testing` and `with comma`.

Comment: Glad you found a helpful solution to your original post. Regarding the additional question in comment a *brute force* work around using the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event might give you some ideas: [Validation data and comma delimited strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485669/excel-vba-validation-data-and-comma-delimited-strings)